# Using characters or Symbols in a positive or negative integer c++ question

Tags: c++, integer

So for a short introduction, im learning c++  and my question is kinda basic, i have been  given a simple c++ question   to check wether an integer  is a positive, negative or zero but there is a fourth condition   and its an error  or unknown value  just in case symbols or characters have been used in the input

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;

    cout << "Enter an integer: " << '\n';
    cin >> num;
    if (num > 0)
        cout << "The number is positive" << '\n';
    else if (num < 0)
        cout << "The number is negative" << '\n';
    else if (num == 0)
        cout << "Zero" << '\n';
    else
        cout << "Error" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, everything works fine  but until one thing  that  while when i used a character  or any other symbol  it reads it as a zero

i know its kinda silly question  but i spent hours  and nothing worked out, i tried removing the  num==0 statement and it worked fine  but  i also  wanted that 0 statement too, any help provided  would be appreciated

Comment: `if(!(cin >> num)) { /* input didn't work! */ }` You can (and should) always check whether `cin >>` succeeded this way.

Comment: You should check the state of `cin` to see if a number was successfully read (note though this will only check that the input starts with a number, it won't check the whole line is valid)

Comment: Checking the status of `cin >> num` will not work correctly if your input is something like "42xyz". In this case, you'll read the 42 leaving "xyz" for later and there will be no error. I think you'll need to read a string and parse it. How exactly you'll do that (just `cin >> word` or with `getline`) depends on whether your input may contain whitespace.

Comment: Input to a std::string and use [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert to a number, the link even shows an example. If that function throws an exception the input was not a valid integer number. And I advice you to look around cppreference a bit more (containers and algorithms too) since it is an invaluable resource for anything C++ and its standard library.

Comment: Side note you really should **stop using** : `using namespace std;`